# XCode 5.0 ambiguous layout warnings

Tags: xcode, cocoa, uistoryboard, xcode5

In my storyboard I have warnings for ambiguous layouts. When I click on the warnings in Xcode's issue-navigator, Xcode opens the storyboard but I have no idea where I am supposed to look to repair the ambiguous layouts. Does anybody know how to get a clear indication where the problems lie?
Thanks
Al

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look for the **little red arrows** on the right of each scene in the Storyboard Editor:

[image]

Click on them and it will tell you what's wrong:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem I was having was that I added view grammatically and didn't add the constraints. When that happens you get a warning but no indication as to where you should look. Add search for addSubviews helped. Thanks.

Comment: @Alan Oh, OK, I see! Mixing storyboard-added view and programmatically added views with auto-layout is kind of hairy.